# Is it possible to use order relation in Presburger arithmetic?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, presburger-arithmetic

> The signature of Presburger arithmetic contains only the addition
> operation and equality, omitting the multiplication operation
> entirely.

Is it possible to state and prove theorems in Presburger arithmetic that contain order relations (less than, <)?

$x + 1 = y → x < y$

Comment: I don't know if it's possible,but it seems that you would at least need to add another axiom for the transitivity of $<$, otherwise you will only be able to prove $x < x + 1$. It can either be directly the transitivity of $<$ or for example $x + 1 < y \to x < y$.

Comment: You can define the ordering from addition alone: $x<y$ iff $\exists z(z+z\not=z\wedge x+z=y)$. So "Presburger with order" is just an expansion by definitions of Presburger arithmetic itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, well-ordering is not *definable* in first-order arithmetic language. Nevertheless, such formulas as the mentioned $x<y\leftrightarrow\exists z(z+z\not=z\wedge x+z=y)$ or $\exists z(x + z = y - 1)$ *express* the notion (viz., implicitly, without an explicit order relation) by dint of the intended domain of quantification, which is $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

As a note for follow-up, I quote (with several additions and notational modifications) a relevant paragraph from Craig Smoryński's *Logical Number Theory I: An Introduction* (Springer, 1991, p. 308):

> Presburger published his result the following year in the proceedings
> of a conference held in Warsaw [*The First Congress of Mathematicians
> of the Slavic Countries, September 23–27, 1929*]. [In the published
> text](https://hdl.handle.net/1813/6478), he only provided the details for the quantifier elimination
> for the structure $\langle\mathbb{Z}, +, 0, 1\rangle$, i.e., the
> addition of the integers. In an addendum, however, he announced that
> the proof could be extended to the case in which the order relation
> was added [*as a primitive notion*]. Since the non-negative integers
> are definable in $\langle\mathbb{Z}, <, +, 0, 1\rangle$, his decision
> procedure covered both structures, $\langle\mathbb{Z}, <, +, 0,
> > 1\rangle$ and $\langle\omega, <, +, 0, 1\rangle$. The full details
> were first published by Paul Bernays in *Grundlagen der Mathematik I*
> in 1934.